# How to See Actual Data Stored in Table Without Running SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in SQL Server 2012 as:

[image]

now can you please let me know how I can I see the actual data stored in the `dbo.UserAccount` table without running expicitly a SQL command like `SELECT * FROM dbo.UserAccount` ?
I tried by clicking on the table node but this just expand the collapse columns nodes.

Comment: Short of backing up the database, taking a course in SQL Server internals and carefully deconstructing the binary file -- no, you're going to need SQL. What, exactly, is your motivation for not wanting to use SQL? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Right click on the table.  One of the options is to show the top records.  Behind the scenes it is still executing SQL though.  If you want to look at the entire table then you are going to be better off using a real front end or writing SQL

Comment: This is sort of like saying you put a bunch of food in the refrigerator and you want to know what is in the fridge without opening the door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `SELECT ... FROM ...`. T-SQL is the *only* API to access SQL Server. You may learn that you can right click a table in SSMS and select 'view top 1000 rows' but that is really just opening a query and running a `SELECT`.